# How do I grab user info from Microsoft Graph for authenticated user using Azure mobile app backend?

Tags: c#, azure-mobile-services, microsoft-graph-api

Using the backend of my app, I am attempting to capture information from Microsoft Graph for a user that has been authenticated and then add that user to a database. The authentication appears to be working correctly, but the user is never added to the database. I am really stuck on this. I've studied the online documentation extensively, but have been unable to find a solution. If I could just tell if the user properties were getting populated, I could figure out what's going on, but I've been unable to do that since the code runs on the server. (I've attempted to remote debug, but have been unable to successfully set a breakpoint.) Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong in the code below?

```cs
class MicrosoftAccountInfo
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string displayName { get; set; }
    public string mail { get; set; }
}

[MobileAppController]
public class MicrosoftAccountController : ApiController
{
    MicrosoftAccountCredentials credentials;
    string msRequestUrl;
    MyAppContext context;
    EntityDomainManager<User> domainManager;

    // GET api/<controller>
    public async Task<User> Get()
    {
        if (credentials == null)
        {
            credentials = await this.User.GetAppServiceIdentityAsync<MicrosoftAccountCredentials>(this.Request);
        }         

        msRequestUrl = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/?$select=id,displayName,mail";

        var client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient();
        var headerValue = "Bearer" + credentials.AccessToken;
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", headerValue);
        var resp = await client.GetAsync(msRequestUrl);
        resp.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        var msInfo = await resp.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        MicrosoftAccountInfo info = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MicrosoftAccountInfo>(msInfo);
        context = new MyAppContext();
        domainManager = new EntityDomainManager<User>(context, Request);
        var user = context.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Email == info.mail);
        if (user == null)
        {
            user = new DataObjects.User { Email = info.mail, UserName = info.displayName, ProviderId = info.id };
            await domainManager.InsertAsync(user);
        }
        else if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(user.ProviderId))
        {
            user.UserName = info.displayName;
            user.ProviderId = info.id;
            await context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        return user;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As to why this is failing, it is difficult to determine without an actual error message. There are simply to many variables/potential failure points involved to say for sure.

That said, you can reduce the number of potential failure points by using the [Microsoft Graph .NET Client Library](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet). There is also a [NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Graph) available: `Install-Package Microsoft.Graph`.

This library will handle composing the Microsoft Graph and deserializing the response into an object. Along with removing a risk factor, it will greatly simplify your code:

```cs
Microsoft.Graph.GraphServiceClient graphClient =
    new Microsoft.Graph.GraphServiceClient(new DelegateAuthenticationProvider((requestMessage) =>
    {
        requestMessage.Headers.Authorization =
            new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", "{your-access-token}");
        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }));

Microsoft.Graph.User user = await graphClient.Me.Request().GetAsync();
```

I would also suggest implementing a monitoring solution that can trap exceptions on the server. This will help with debugging. If you're running on Azure, I strongly recommend using [Application Insights](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/application-insights/). Aside from being free to get started, it is effectively a "click once, get monitoring" solution. It will handle wiring up the server and provide reporting for any exceptions it runs into.

*Note that you can also use App Insights with your own servers or apps hosted on other services (i.e. AWS, RackSpace), there may however be some manual configuration required.*

Comment: Thanks, Marc.  I followed your advice and got Application Insights set up.  It's reporting a GET /favicon.ico request is failing with a 404 response.  I'm new to Azure, but does that mean the error is unrelated to the code I supplied?  Next, I'll switch to the Microsoft Graph .NET Client Library as well.

Comment: That `404` means you're requesting a file (`/favicon.ico`) that doesn't exist on the server.  Just a guess but this likely means your page has something along the lines of `<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">` in it's HTML.

Comment: I've made some progress.  My issue now is that the line, Microsoft.Graph.User user = await graphClient.Me.Request().GetAsync, is generating the following error: Error Operation=MicrosoftAccountController.ExecuteAsync, Exception=System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> Microsoft.Graph.ServiceException: Code: InvalidAuthenticationToken Message: CompactToken parsing failed with error code: 8004920A.  Any suggestions?  Thanks.

Comment: A little more info ... It looks like I am successfully retrieving authentication token.  Microsoft Graph just doesn't like it for some reason.

Comment: Follow up questions should be posted as new questions. When they get tacked into comments they become impossible for other users on SO to find.

Comment: Sorry about that.  I'm new to StackOverflow.